# Why is `%!xxd -r` result wrong while `xxd -r` from console with the same input works correctly?

Tags: binary-file, xxd

I have the following file named `asterix`:

```
0000000: 15 00 1f c1 13 31 49 80 02 64 01 08 42 48 ef 28             
0000010: 2d cd 0c 02 00 07 f1 e9 1b 04 63 30 c7 08 20
```

When I open this file in vim, I do `%!xxd -r`, then `%!xxd -g1`. I get this:

```
0000000: 15 00 1f d0 b0 13 31 49 e2 94 80 02 64 01 08 42  ...1I...d..B
0000010: 48 d0 9e 28 2d d0 bc 0c 02 00 07 d0 af d0 98 1b  H..(-...
0000020: 04 63 30 d0 b3 08 20 0a                          .c0... .
```

But if in `bash` I do `xxd -r < asterix | xxd -g1`, I get the expected result:

```
0000000: 15 00 1f c1 13 31 49 80 02 64 01 08 42 48 ef 28  ...1I..d..BH.(
0000010: 2d cd 0c 02 00 07 f1 e9 1b 04 63 30 c7 08 20     -...c0..
```

I've tried doing `e ++enc=c` in vim to prevent possible interference of encoding, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

So what's going on? How do I make vim work correctly with binary data (up to newline at the end, of course)?

I'm using VIM 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 2 2014 19:39:59) on Ubuntu 14.04. When I run vim with `env -i vim asterix`, it works as expected. But if I run it as usually, but logging in as a different user (the one without custom vim config, by e.g. `su -`), the above described behavior persists.

I've now noticed that `env -i` works because it resets locale. My default locale is this:

```
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

Setting `LC_CTYPE=C`, I get Vim to work correctly (it appends `0a` to the end, but it's OK). Still I'd like to know why locale interferes with calling `xxd -r`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Vim 8.0.0056, Ubuntu 16.04. I get the expected result.

Comment: @muru I'm using VIM 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:59) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Good old Ubuntu and its hopelessly out of date repositories (we can't be rushing into crazy new versions of Vim now, can we?)

Comment: @DrEval 14.04 is an LTS version of Ubuntu, it's meant to provide only fixes, not major upgrades.

Comment: What's the preferred way of upgrading stuff like vim, flac etc?  Is the choice: 1)compiling from source (tedious), 2)using a private ppa(risky), 3)looking for a tar(risky) or is there a better way I'm missing?

Comment: MacVim 8.0.237, with Zsh here, I can reproduce OP's issue. But running the following seems to work:  `:%!xxd -r | xxd -g1`

Comment: Might be an artifact of the shell being used. Which one are you using? Can you also reproduce with `vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: @muru I'm using bash. And yes, I do reproduce the problem even with these options, although the resulting hex dump differs from the one I get without the options (still remaining the same in length — longer than the correct one).

Comment: @muru seems it's related to locale. See update.

Comment: Try loading the file in binary mode

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt OK, this does work. So even without "loading a file", i.e. just starting `vim -b`, pasting the text and doing `%!xxd -r` and `%!xxd -g1` makes it work. You might want to turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: notice after posting there's already this answer in the comments.

Run `vim` in binary mode as `vim -b asterix`. I think the problem has something to do with conversions caused by `encoding`/`fileencoding` settings.

If your file is already loaded, you can switch to binary mode without leaving vim. Save the file, then do `:e ++bin`.